# jQuery - target specific element with same class

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jq to excuse me if I'm not clear enough.

fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/tWHpA/1/
```

On hover both divs slide up, how an I make it to slide up only the div that's been hovered on?

html:

```
<div class="span1 green 1"><div class="hover">tile title</div><a href="#page2" rel="ajax"></a></div>
<div class="green 2"><div class="hover">tile1 title</div></div>
```

css:

```
.green {width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; color: white; position: relative; z-index:100;}      
.hover {width: 100px; height: 50px; background: yellow; position: absolute; bottom:0; display:none; z-index:-1;   }
```

jq:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.green').addClass('.hover');


   $('.green').hover(function() {

          $('.hover').stop(true, true).slideDown('1000')

    },

    //Mouseout, fadeOut the hover class


    function() {

        $('.hover').stop(true, true).slideUp('1000');

    }).click(function() {

        //Add selected class if user clicked on it
        $(this).addClass('selected');


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.green').addClass('.hover');
    $('.green').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.hover').stop(true, true).slideDown('1000')
    },

    function () {
        $(this).find('.hover').stop(true, true).slideUp('1000');

    }).click(function () {

        //Add selected class if user clicked on it
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside your event handler, use `$(this)` instead of `$(".hover")`.

This will operate on only the element that is receiving the event instead of all the elements.  `this` is set by jQuery to be the element that triggered the event.

```
$('.green').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).slideDown('1000')
},function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).slideUp('1000');
}).click(function() {
    //Add selected class if user clicked on it
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

I think you have a logic problem though because once you slide up, the element that is no longer hovered, then there is no way to put the mouse over it again to get it to drop down.

After changing your logic a bit, you can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6Szyb/

Comment: was trying exactly the same, but doesn't do it for me

Comment: @user1339164 - see the comment I added at the end of my answer because you have a logic problem.  If you slideUp when the mouse leaves, then there's no way to ever get the element to slideDown again because you can't hover an element that isn't visible.  You need to explain more clearly what you're trying to accomplish in your design.

Comment: @user1339164 - After changing your logic a bit (to elements don't get hidden), you can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6Szyb/